# What does "practice" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this quote:

> DROP OF A HAT - Acting readily or on some single signal. In the 19th century it was occasionally the **practice** in the United States to signal the start of a fight or a race by dropping a hat or sweeping it downward while holding it in the hand. The quick response to the signal found its way into the language for any action that begins quickly without much need for prompting.

Looking up OALD, there are three definitions that seems relevant to the context, but I'm not sure which one is the most appropriate, they are:

> 1 [uncountable] action rather than ideas
> *the theory and practice of teaching*
> *She's determined to put her new ideas into practice.*
>
> 2 [uncountable, countable] a way of doing something that is the usual or expected way in a particular organization or situation
> *common/current/standard practice*
> *guidelines for good practice*
> *a review of pay and working practices*
> *religious practices*
> *child care policy and practice*
>
> 3 [countable] a thing that is done regularly; a habit or a custom
> *the German practice of giving workers a say in how their company is run*
> *It is his practice to read several books a week.*

Comment: #2 is the most apt; the dropping of a hat was a common, usual, or expected way of signaling the start of a race.

Comment: Definition 3 is what fits, rather than 2. This is a custom, and not like a standard practice according to an organization's guidelines.

Comment: I don't see a whole lot of difference between 2 and 3, and think either one has some applicability.

Comment: @J.R. right, but to a native ear, when you first read the passage, what occured to you as the meaning of *practice*?

Comment: @Theo - No matter what context I heard the word "practice" in, I wouldn't think of any of those dictionary definitions – not word-for-word, at least. If you had asked me for a synonym off the top of my head, I probably would have offered "custom" (which aligns nicely with #3), but I wouldn't argue with "expected way," either.

Comment: I agree with everyone overall that two and three are essentially the same; but @Kaz, if you read them closely, number three indicates a regular custom, whereas two indicates a custom that is either practiced occasionally or only by some people. Number three suggests something that'd be considered a tradition or a societal norm. Since this was an occasionally practiced custom, number three doesn't fit.

Comment: @Theo two and three both reference customs. The difference is only with the frequency or with the level of adaptation by society. Just because two doesn't explicitly use the word *custom*, doesn't mean it's not one. A practice is a custom.

Comment: @JohnQPublic I would have said a practice is a [custom](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/custom) once it's become [customary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/customary).  In other words, I think a practice may be a custom, but it isn't always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number two most closely matches your example, although two and three are **very similar.**

Here's the difference between two and three in case that's what's causing your confusion: Number two indicates a custom that is sometimes practiced, yet not regularly, whereas number three indicates that it is the expected norm.

The word *occasionally* is the contextual cue that indicates it's number two; but again, the difference is subtle.

Answer (score 0):

2, as it refers to the spontaneity of the action rather than the predictability of it or requirement for it.

In the context of, say, a Formula 1 race, it could be a flag, or a dropping of the starter's hand, or the dropping of a hat. The usual practice is to start the race with *some* signal from the starter, which *may* be the dropping of a hat.